# Are two groups equal or isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

> Let $G$ be a finite commutative group and $H, K$ be two subgroups (hence normal) of $G$ such that
> for some some $g\in G$, $H=\langle g\rangle$, $K=\langle g^2 \rangle$ and $|g|=|g^2|$.
>
> Can we say the factor groups $G/H$ and $G/K$ are isomorphic? If yes, can we further tell if they are equal? And if they are non-isomorphic, what should I add to establish isomorphism or equality?

I believe the factor groups $G/H$ and $G/K$ are not only isomorphic, they are equal as well. Both factor groups are in the same order. I tried to show they are equal, by choosing an arbitrary element $\alpha:=aH$ from $G/H$. This would be equal to $bK\in G/K$ for some $b\in G$, provided
$$aH=bK\Leftrightarrow a\langle g\rangle=b\langle g^2 \rangle$$
is solvable for $b$. The problem now reduces to determine $b$.

To establish this, let $x\in a\langle g\rangle$. Then $x=ag^r$ for some integer $r$ and so $g^r=a^{-1}x$ i.e. $g^{2r}=a^{-2}x^2$, since $G$ is commutative. Then
$x=x^{-1}a^2 (g^2)^r$. Choosing $b=x^{-1}a^2$ we finally have $x\in b\langle g^2\rangle$. Thus
$aH\subseteq bK$. Proceeding, in the same manner, $bK\subseteq aH$ and finally $\alpha\in G/K$.

Is this correct? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Also, feel free to edit if any correction is required in typesetting.

Comment: The groups $H$ and $K$ are finite, so if $|g| = |g^2|$, then $H = K$. So $G/H = G/K$.

Comment: To elaborate, $K\subset H$, and they have orders $|g|$ and $|g^2|$, respectively. Since $|g|=|g^2|$, by finiteness, $K=H$.

Comment: @spin   So nicely done. Can you suggest if my approach was correct, I mean whether determination of $b$ as done above is correct.

Comment: @KentaS Thanks a lot. Beautifully done :-) One question, suppose H is cyclic and there is a bijection between the subgroups $H$ and $K$, then would the arguments given above work?

Comment: For $G=\mathbb Z/2\times\mathbb Z/4$, quotienting out by $H=\mathbb Z/2\times 0$ and quotienting out by $K=\mathbb Z/2\times2\mathbb Z/4$ is different.

Comment: @KentaS I beg your pardon, but is there any bijection between $H$ and  $K$ ? I could not understand that part.

Comment: Sorry I meant $K=0\times2\mathbb Z/4$.

Comment: The question of equality does not make sense if $H\neq K$.  One of the $H$-cosets is $H$ itself, and this is not equal to any $K$-coset unless $H=K$.

Comment: @JBL If $|g|=|g^2|$, doesn't that indicate $\langle g \rangle=H=K=\langle g^2\rangle$ ?

Comment: Yes (in the finite case).  And from $H=K$ the conclusion $G/H=G/K$ is trivial.

Comment: @JBL ok. I understand. Thanks